# Elections in the United States of Alfagonia

Tags: mathematics, tiling, polyomino

Elections were held in the 45 electoral districts of the United States of Alfagonia. The Green Party won the election in 23 of the 45 districts. Alfagonia is made up of nine states of five districts, each of the states in the shape of a pentomino. According to the Constitution of Alfagonia, the winner of the election is not the party which wins the most districts, but the party which wins the most states.

Given that, based on the Constitution, this particular election was won by the Red Party, is it possible to determine the boundaries between the nine states of the Union?

[image]

Comment: Should we assume that the winner of each state is the party that won the majority of the districts?

Comment: Must the pentominoes be distinct?

Comment: This seems really underconstrained.

Comment: @xnor Perhaps it's a veiled critique of gerrymandering?

Answer (score 8):

I think this can be achieved easily... I just greedily divide the states and this is one solution I got.

> [image]

Comment: And it's not hard to see there are a lot of other possible solutions.

Comment: In that case shoudn't your answer be negative, because you demonstrate it is not possible to **determine** the boundaries?